# Trying to uninstall a theme, but it's hijacking my home page

Tags: themes, homepage, customization

I'm trying to install Thesis on [my blog](http://aspirecode.com), and I'm having an issue that's caused by the theme that's currently active, which is [Structure by Okay Themes](http://themes.okaythemes.com/docs/structure/).

This theme created a static home page when I installed it, but not in [the way recommended by the WordPress docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page).

When I activate Thesis, the home page returns an empty HTML doc.

I'm a developer, so I'm comfortable monkeying around behind the scenes, but I'm not sure where to start. Did the theme install a custom PHP file and set it as the home page?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

### Update

The `options` table has a `current_theme` value that names Structure:

```
+-----------+---------------+--------------+----------+
| option_id | option_name   | option_value | autoload |
+-----------+---------------+--------------+----------+
|       158 | current_theme | Structure    | yes      |
+-----------+---------------+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: What have you done to remove the "Structure" theme? Or how are you trying to uninstall it? Have you tried just deleting the files via FTP?

Comment: So far all I've done is deactivate it. I tried activating both Thesis and the 2013 theme, and in both cases `http://aspirecode.com` just returns an empty HTML file.

Comment: Did you try changing the Settings > Reading option for `Front page displays` to `Your latest posts` so thesis will not use a static page?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the theme is hanging when you try to disable it.

Physically remove the theme. Login over FTP and delete or rename the theme directory. If that doesn't work this will take a lot of debugging. WordPress will notice that the active theme is gone/broken and load a default theme.

---

***I tell you the following with great caution.*** Try this only if no other options are available, and just before you cash out and reinstall.

You can also try manually switching themes. Search the `$wpdb->options` table for `current_theme` in the `option_name` column and change the associated `option_value` to "Twenty Thirteen" (I am assuming that theme is on your system"). Do the same with the `template` and `stylesheet` values but change them to "twentythirteen". Edit carefully. You can break things. That will force a theme switch, or it does when I try.

As with any database edit, back things up thoroughly first. This has been tested but not thoroughly. **Do not ignore the "back things up" part**. If you don't know how to back up the *database* (not the PHP files), then stop.

I don't know what else your theme might have done, so no guarantees. The fact that renaming the directory did not help gives me pause. There will still be entries in the database that should probably be cleaned up.

Comment: Renaming the Structure theme folder produced the same result. The [setup for this theme](http://themes.okaythemes.com/docs/structure/) involves a data import--could that have set up a different home page?

Comment: Argghhh... try looking through the `$wpdb->options` table for referenced to the theme. Look for `current_theme` in the `option_name` column first. This could be painful.

Comment: I found the `current_theme` value, and it points to Structure. See update above.

Comment: @JoshEarl : see the edit

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have already checked this, but perhaps there is an active plugin which is referring to a file in that theme.  I would suggest deactivating all plugins and then manually remove the theme.  If you still have trouble you may need to repair/optimize the database.

Comment: Good thought--there was a plugin, but deactivating it didn't help. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this: move the current wordpress installation folder aside and create a new installation of wordpress, bring your settings and files over as if you're migrating your site but don't bring the troublesome theme.